# How to loop through files of certain extensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to loop through a folder and all subfolders to find all files of certain file types - for example, only .mp4, .avi, .wmv.

Here is what I have now, it loops through all file types:

```
import os
rootdir = 'input'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
     for file in files:
          print (os.path.join(subdir, file))
```

> Warning: above code sample will run indefinitely and may yield out of memory

Comment: For beginners who came here through search, note that the OP's code recurses through subdirectories and finds all files with a particular extension in an entire directory tree (folders withing folders within folders etc within a starting folder).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `os.path.splitext` which takes a path and splits the file extension from the end of it:

```
import os
rootdir = 'input'
extensions = ('.mp4', '.avi', '.wmv')

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        ext = os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower()
        if ext in extensions:
            print (os.path.join(subdir, file))
```

Comment: Thanks ozgur, this code is closest to what I had originally - easy to understand as well. The other answers might be more efficient if done on large-scale (did not test!), but for my simple tasks this will perfectly suffice.

Answer (score 29):

For multiple extensions, the simplest is just to use `str.endswith` passing a tuple of substrings to check:

```
  for file in files:
      if file.endswith((".avi",".mp4","wmv")):
         print (os.path.join(subdir, file))
```

You could use `iglob` like below and chain the searches returned or use re.search but using `endswith` is probably the best approach.

```
from itertools import chain
from glob import iglob

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in chain.from_iterable(iglob(os.path.join(rootdir,p)) for p in ("*.avi", "*.mp4", "*wmv")) :
            print(os.path.join(subdir, file))
```

Using `python3.5` [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) now supports recursive searches with the ** syntax:

```
from itertools import chain
from glob import iglob

from glob import iglob
for file in chain.from_iterable(iglob(os.path.join(rootdir,p)) 
      for p in (rootdir+"**/*.avi", "**/*.mp4", "**/*wmv")):
          print(file)
```

Answer (score 4):

I actually did something similar to this a couple of days ago and here is how I did it:

```
EXTENSIONS = ('.cpp','.hpp')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(EXTENSIONS):
            #file which ends with extension type so do your thing!
```

Hope this is what you are after. You can see the whole script here on my [github](https://github.com/samredway/scripts/blob/master/lcount.py).

Comment: Very clear and nice code. Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

This one line solution might also be useful to get all `.py` file in present directory

```
for file in list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.py'), os.listdir('./'))):
    print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.4 you can use `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import chain

rootdir = 'input'
p = Path(rootdir)
for file in (chain(p.glob('**/*.mp4'), p.glob('**/*.avi'))):
    print(file)
```