# Is there an easy way in Python to get a file by name without knowing the extension?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a subdirectory set up such that there will be many different image files, each with a different name and a few possible extensions.

For example, let's say my directory is laid out like this:

```
.
├── img/
│   ├── bar.gif
│   ├── baz.jpg
│   ├── foo.png
│   └── foobar.png
└── main.py
```

(There won't be situations like `foo.png` and `foo.gif` both existing. Also, the only file extensions being used will be `.png`, `.gif`, and `.jpg`/`.jpeg`.)

In this example, I would like to be able to open `foobar.jpg` just by knowing the name `foobar`.

Is this possible with Python? Is there a PyPI module I might need to use? Thank you!

Comment: For looping over [a directory with a list of file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948528/python-loop-through-files-of-certain-extensions)

Comment: Sure, look through the files and match `foobar`

Comment: You can give a try to the glob module

Comment: @DarrylG That's perfect, thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, glob would be good for this. Usually, I prefer using `pathlib`, so `from pathlib import Path`, then `for file in Path(directory_path).glob('foobar*'): do_something(file)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's even better since I'm already using `pathlib` in that program, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the file structure given in the example in the question:

```
from pathlib import Path

names = ['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'foobar']

for name in names:
    for fn in Path('img').glob(f'{name}.*'):
        print(f'Found {fn}')
```

Should give you the output:

```
Found img\bar.gif
Found img\baz.jpg
Found img\foo.png
Found img\foobar.png
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I used as it was suggested in a comment on the question. Thank you so much for your help!